# Removing files from git history - bad revision error

Tags: git

I am following the instructions on Github (https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) to tidy up a messy repository.  I have successfully cleared out all the .csv files using

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.csv' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

And now need to remove all the .docx files.  However, when I use exactly the same command with *.docx instead, I get an error saying:
`fatal: bad revision ' --prune-empty'`

I pushed to the origin on github, and cloned a fresh copy before doing this second lot of updates.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong/differently that is causing this error.  Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I believe that the documentation you are making reference to assumes that you are using __Gig Bash__.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved... I took out the space after the backslash which I'd been putting in before the `--prune-empty` part, and it works as expected now!
No idea why it works though....

Comment: You rock bro. Saved my life. :) Been facing the issue for entire day because of this. I ran the command neglecting the `--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` part and everything happened correctly. except it created double commits issue.

Comment: I think this is not very clear from their documentation as well. As, the command is divided in 3 lines and we naturally assume there is a space after 2nd line. If we are not to assume that, we definitely put a space after 1st line then. Such a waste of time this issue was.

Comment: If running on *nix, and you took the command from the help.github.com site, then this is all you need to do.

Answer (score 76):

Git should run from either cmd.exe or bash.

The problem is the use of `'` in your command. Windows only uses `"`.
The command you are looking for is:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
"git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.csv" \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: This would make a lot of sense!  Sadly I don't have a windows machine any longer to test this, but hopefully useful for other people :)

Comment: This is the Windows answer

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar error (`fatal: bad revision 'rm'`) when running it from Windows command line and I couldn't solve it removing spaces as you did.

But I could solve it running the same exact command from git bash command line.
Maybe this could help somebody with same issue.

Comment: Helped me. Had to remove the space as well but then good to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

None of the suggested answers worked for me, they worked without backslashes though

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.csv" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: I had to do the same in Windows, changing single for double speechmarks to avoid the error ```fatal: bad revision 'rm'``` and then put onto 1 line without the forward slashes to avoid the error ```'--prune-empty' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```. However my file has a space in it so it seems it is not finding it. Can I ask how you do it if your file has a space as cannot add speechmarks again. I tried an asterix but it just says ```WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged```.

Comment: @RobinWilson I don't know, sorry. Can you escape the quotes with a backslash, or an additional quote?

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it wouldn't work either. It appears this doesn't work ```File*Name.txt``` but this does ```*Name.txt``` but would only work if you wanted to delete all files ending in Name.txt. This said it had found the correct number of instances of the file but then when I pushed the changes it still didn't remove them when reviewing on github.com so I'm at a loss. Don't know why they can't make it a bit easier!

Comment: This worked for me as well on windows cmd shell.  Removed the backslashes and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Code terminal, write it with double-quotation and without backslashes:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.csv" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me on Windows:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "git rm -f --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/file.txt" -- --all
```

it rewrote all the histories and after `git push` I could see the result on the repo.

Comment: Great. Am having trouble deleted a huge file. Let me try this